# Jenkins and Bitbucket integration

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I want to setup Jenkins job which will do following task.

1. Pull code from Git repositories which resides on Bitbucket. I have repository URL and login credentials for the same repository. I am not the repository's admin. I don't want to create any hooks for the repository.
2. Build this code with existing ant script along with test execution.
3. Deploy on server if the build is successful.

I am stuck at task 1: pull code from repository. I need help to solve this. On the Jenkins side, I am using Git plugin.

Comment: These are pretty basic tasks. What have you tried so far? Start by looking at the [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

Comment: Please do not mix Markdown and HTML in your question...

Answer (score 2):

To pull code from Bitbucket repository, you need:

Step 1: Make sure you have Git Plugin installed. If not, you can install from `Manage Jenkins->Manage Plugins->Avaliable`

Step 2: use `ssh-keygen` to generate a ssh key pair and upload your ssh public key to Bitbucket site so that your machine can communicate with Bitbucket server(If you already done this, then please see Step 3 directly.)

Step 3: Create a job, from its configuration page, Under `Source Code Management` choose `git`, and put your repo address of Bitbucket into the `Repository URL`

Save the job, and click the `Build Now`, it should work.